# Strange Error with Libertine and pdfpages

Tags: errors, pdftex, pdfpages, libertine

Frequently I have to make a compilation of documents. Each document has been produced with pdfLaTeX, and the compilation is done with pdfLaTeX and the package pdfpages.

MWE of my file »libertine-fehler1.pdf«:

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\emph{Here we go.}
\end{document}
```

The result is as expected:

[image: Pichture of the result1]

Now, I reuse this PDF in my compilation. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{libertine-fehler1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I get the very surprising result:

[image: Libertine error 2]

As you can see, there a squares instead of letters, and the »H«, which is readable, is not in italics.

Any ideas? I'm using the old libertine package of the year 2011, and TeXlive 2012, but Libertine is installed in texmf-local. Everything else works, so it does not seem to be an error of the installation.

Comment: First of all, remove the Libertine fonts in `texmf-local` (just rename the directories), remove the map file from the relevant `updmap.cfg` file and update TeX Live 2012.

Comment: @egreg No, I cannot do that, because I need the old Linux Libertine package. It provides e.g. the command \libertineGlyph{}. None of the new packages provides that.

Comment: It's quite certainly a conflict between fonts in different locations.

Comment: Your example works fine using the new `libertine` package.

Comment: Use in the document with pdfpages `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1`. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28350/linux-libertine-and-pdftex-glyph-a-undefined/28352#28352.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That does the trick. Thank you very much. I just found out that it does not bloat the size of the second file much. And in the cases of my compilation, size does not matter much. Would you make an answer instead of a comment, pleazzze?!!!

Comment: JFYI: The latest version of the _new_ `libertine` package has `\libertineGlyph` (and also `\biolinumGlyph` and `\libertineInitialGlyph`) for the OpenType font version.

Comment: @Speravir As far as I can see, they only are available for LuaTeX and XeTeX. I'll be glad to change to LuaTex when it reaches version 1.00, but not earlier, because I'm earning a living by writing contracts and letters and this is cumbersome enough.