# pdflatex: glyph ... undefined. How to properly solve this problem?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols

I use the package [`newpx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx) with pdflatex (on Ubuntu 20.04, texlive installation), and I'm seeing a "glyph `section' undefined" error. Here's a minimal working example and the output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpx}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
a b \S a b § a b

Palatino
\end{document}
```

[image]

Error log:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/newpx/zplr.pfb): glyph `section' undefined
```

I'm seeing many questions here reporting this problem ([example 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/322010/97039), [example 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28350/97039)). Some answers suggest to use `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` in the preamble. In my case this doesn't solve the problem. Moreover [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28350/linux-libertine-and-pdftex-glyph-a-undefined#comment55690_28352) says

> `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts` is a work-around. [...] The real solution would be to correct the internal font names.

How to correct the internal font names, or how to check if they have any problems?

In my system I see only one installation of `TeXGyrePagella` and the fonts `zplr` used by `newpx`, so I don't understand what's meant with "internal font names".

Should I submit a bug to the maintainer of `newpx`?

For the record, this also happens with the `newpxtext` package, but I don't remember it happening a year ago.

Comment: I _think_ this is a bug in the type1 version of the font and should be reported to the maintainer (lualatex works on your test file using the opentype font)

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, I'll report the bug then.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is a bug. In ntx-ec-tlf.enc `/section` must be replaced by `/uni00A7`.

Comment: To confirm what @UlrikeFischer wrote if you copy /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/newtx/ntx-ec-tlf.enc  to the directory with your document and change `/section` to `/uni00A7` on line 163 then your document works as expected

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer ! I also confirm that the correction works. I wrote to M. Sharpe, the maintainer, to report the bug. I'll PS this detail.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please feel free to write your comment as an answer, I'll happily mark that as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `pfbtopfa` on `zplr.pfb` a low level PostScript error is raised.

So it's definitely a bug in the last version of `zplr.pfb`.

As a temporary workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewCommandCopy\latextextsection\textsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\textsection}{}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \use:c { f@family } } { \familydefault }
   {
    {\fontfamily{qpl}\selectfont\latextextsection}
   }
   {\latextextsection}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

a b \S a b § a b

Palatino

\textsf{a b \S a b § a b}

\end{document}
```

This uses TeX Gyre Pagella for the missing glyph, but only if the font family is the default one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I modified the `ntx-ec-tlf.enc` file directly as suggested by @ulrikefischer, and that solved the problem. But this is useful for people who don't have access to the texlive directory.